# Django - improve performance of queryset with annotate

Tags: mysql, django, performance, django-queryset

I am having some performance problems with an `annotate` call in a Django QuerySet.  Let me explain my question with an example.  Say I have a foreign key relationship in my model like this:

```
def Blog(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
   title = models.CharField()

def BlogArticle(models.Model):
   blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
   title = models.CharField()
   body = models.CharField()
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now, say I want to get a list of the last 10 updated blogs based on the timestamps of the blog articles.  I could do this with:

```
latest_updates = Blog.objects.annotate(updated=Max('blogarticle__timestamp')).order_by('-updated')[:10]
```

This works, but is slow with MySQL with lots of data (profiling the query shows the "Copying to tmp table" step taking a long time, but that's another topic).

So far I've considered the following:

- Add an "updated" `DateTimeField` to `Blog` and add a signal or `save` override to keep this field in sync with the latest `BlogArticle` for that `Blog`.  This would be great for performance, but goes against the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.
- Query the `BlogArticle` model for the last 10 updates, and use that to query the `Blog` model.  However, this would only work if the last 10 updates are all from different blogs.

Any other ideas to optimize this query?

Answer (score 3):

try adding ad index to the timestamp column:

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

HTH